Project check for mounting TV to a wall
I was trying to secure a 75 inch tv to a wall with a fullmotion mount. The mount is not wide enough to across two studs so I decide to secure it to a plywood then to the wall.
Here is the plan:
I got a piece of 3/4 plywood goes across 3 studs and secure them using structure screws (specifically Fastenmaster 3-1/2") to the stud.
The screw says no predrill is needed but Im a bit skeptic about that. Another question is: Is this lag bolt needed?
I don`t have a plan how I secure the mount to the plywood, should I just use bolt and nut? also someone suggest a 12g timber tek screws.
Help is appreciated.

I would definitely pre-drill with big screws like those. Use a bit just a little smaller than the smooth part of the screws. And don't pre-drill the full length of the screw, but probably around 2" or so. However, be careful - 3.5" is a bit risky. You have 0.75" of plywood + 0.5" of drywall. That would put a 3.5" screw 2.25" into the studs. There can be wires or plumbing pipes in the middle of the studs. If there are any wires or pipes less than 1.25" from the edge of the stud then their should be a nail plate to prevent accidentally drilling into the wires or pipes. Which means the recommended total screw length for an unknown wall is: extra stuff (0.75" plywood) + drywall (0.5") + 1.25" = 2.5". So that's how long your screws should be. No need for lag bolts.
As far as attaching the mount to the plywood, any decent wood screws should do fine. Minimum length is 3/4" to use the full thickness of the plywood, but a little longer makes sense as there is no problem going into the drywall a little bit and the mount isn't (I hope) paper-thin, so its thickness counts too. Not bolts and nuts - how would you attach the nut?

My initial plan was to drill bolt holes behind the plywood, washer and nut in front the plywood to secure the mount. Also some people prefer beefy lag bolts over structure screws, I have no idea if structure screw is enough to secure the plywood to the stud.

That's more work than needed and would also mean that if you wanted to move the mount a few inches in one direction or another, or replace the mount, you would have to take the plywood down - all much more work than needed. 3/4" plywood is thick enough and strong enough to hold TV mount & TV with decent screws going into the plywood.

If you do what you're thinking you will need to make countersink divots in the wall for your bolt heads.  Which is, of course, not the end of the world, but it's more extra work.
